# How to follow a variable value during runtime?

Tags: r, debugging

I have a large list of dataframes `dataset` that I try to fuse into one dataframe and I would like to check the speed of the process because the list is large and it takes a lot of time and I don't know if I'm supposed to wait. How to check the current index that `do.call` is currently working on during runtime ?

```
dataset <- do.call(rbind, dataset)
```

Comment: The short answer is you can't. But there are faster alternatives, like `rbindlist` from **data.table** (and `rbind_all` from **dplyr** will probably also be faster).

Comment: Perhaps a little older than `dplyr`, but this is pretty straightforward with `plyr` as well. `library(plyr); ldply(dataset, identity, .progress = "text");`

Comment: ok I see I will have to learn the data.table package I wanted to avoid that but I now understand it's quite mandatory